# Center tooltip with CSS on mouseover

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have searched many custom css tooltips.  I have combined a couple into one that i really like but I have an issue and I hope it is solvable.

The issue I can not solve is how to make the tooltip centered over the mouse.  The javascript is what makes it moved over the mouse so I am sure there is some code right around "e.clientX" that i need to add to it to center it instead of just set 60px but dont really know javascript.

Here is a fiddle of it: http://jsfiddle.net/kkx9uhu1/
If you hover over the color squares a tooltip that customized with CSS shows up.

```
    var x = (e.clientX - 60) + 'px',
    y = (e.clientY - 40) + 'px'; // Here the 60 should be something to center the tooltip instead
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just divide the width by 2 and that'll center it:

```
    window.onmousemove = function (e) {

        for (var i = 0; i < tooltips.length; i++) {

            tooltips[i].style.top = (e.clientY - 40) + 'px';
            tooltips[i].style.left = (e.clientX - (tooltips[i].offsetWidth / 2)) + 'px';
        }
    };
```

The jsFiddle's **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/kkx9uhu1/1/)**. Also, note that I changed the CSS too: on `.tooltiptext` I removed the margin 20px and changed the position to absolute. Also, no need to cache the X and Y values into variables since you're using these values only once. Finally, there's a CSS error in your original fiddle line 20 with `Left` not being a valid property.

Comment: Can you tell me the reason you changed it from relative to absolute.  Just for future understanding.  Thank you so much.

Comment: @PeterBrink: just from experience. If I need to tweak the position of something manually, then I want to make sure I set the whole thing; if you choose relative then that means the positioning depends on some other element's position, and that may change if the site later changes. For instance, in your case I struggled a few minutes to figure out why despite the js code the element wasn't centered: there was a 20px margin! In a nutshell, you want positioning to depend on as few things as possible.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add the tooltip's width into your calculation.

```
window.onmousemove = function (e) {

    for (var i = 0; i < tooltips.length; i++) {
        var width = tooltips[i].offsetWidth;
        var x = (e.clientX - (width)/2) + 'px',
            y = (e.clientY - 40) + 'px';

        tooltips[i].style.top = y;
        tooltips[i].style.left = x;
    }
};
```

Here is an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hhgqfbdt/)